# partial derivative

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

I'm new to Mathematica, and I'm still learning. I'm trying to code this partial differentiation. Can someone please help me find out where I coded wrong? I've attached a hand-written solution below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your code, not images. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`D[x1Com,x[1,i]]` will give zero, since there is no `x[1,i]` any more in `x1Com`. There is only `x[1,1]` and `x[1,2]` and so on.

One way could be

```
ClearAll[x1Com, x, m];
x1Com = HoldForm@(Sum[(m[1, i]*x[1, i]), {i, 1, 6}]/Sum[m[1, i], {i, 1, 6}])
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now make a function to differentiate w.r.t. to specific `x[1,i]`

```
diff[x1Com_, x_] := D[ReleaseHold@x1Com, x];
```

Now use it

```
diff[x1Com, x[1, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
diff[x1Com, x[1, 2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And so on.